# What is the meaning of "fit the time" in the context?

Tags: meaning, context

check out the sentence:

> As measurement devices have improved, maps have become more accurate
>   and also less artistic. The following maps are from the region in
>   which the current superpowers, Russia and the United States, almost
>   meet. The older map (L126) is from the early 17th century. It was
>   drawn by John Speed (1552–1629), an English cartographer and
>   historian. At first his life took another direction when he followed
>   his father into the tailoring business. It was not until later that
>   his interest in history became an occupation. The map on display was
>   published in a history book written by Speed. The details that fit the
>   time include a drawing of Willem Barentsz’s crew spending the winter
>   on Novaya Zemlya

I couldn't find the precise meaning of "fit the time" in dictionary.

Thanks

Comment: It's not real clear, especially without further context, but I'm guessing that it means details that are "appropriate to the era".

Comment: I presume the "Speed" mentioned is John Speed, an historian and cartographer from the early 1600s.  Willem Barentsz is the explorer from the late 1500s for whom Barents Sea north of Scandinavia was named.  You should edit your question to include such contextual information.

Comment: You should also include a link to the source  if it is online.

Comment: I've put the whole context

Comment: "fit the time" in this context means "not anachronistic" or "characteristic of that time period."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ***[fit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fit)*** means:

> - to be suitable for something:
>
>   - With her qualifications, she should fit the job perfectly.
>       Let the punishment fit the crime.
>       I'm sure we'll have something to fit your requirements.

Cambridge Dictionary

- Fit the time in the sense that the details are  proper for the historical period of time which the maps date back to.